# $L^2$ uniform integrability in terms of Fourier coefficients

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, compactness

Given a bounded sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $L^2(\mathbf{T})$ where $\mathbf{T}:=\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$, the strong compactness of $(f_n)_n$ is equivalent to $$\lim_N \sup_n \sum_{|k|\geq N} |c_k(f_n)|^2=0,$$ where $(c_k(f_n))_{k\in \mathbf{Z}}$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f_n$. This criteria expresses a condition of (uniform) decay on those coefficients in order to get compactness.

Now, let's assume furthermore that the sequence $(f_n)_n$ converges a.e. (to $0$, w.l.o.g.). In that case, compactness for $(f_n)_n$ is equivalent to its $L^2$-uniform integrability (that is :  uniform integrability of $(f_n^2)_n$).

Is there any (refined) criteria on the Fourier coefficients in this situation ? I chose the $L^2(\mathbf{T})$ framework to exemplify the criteria above, but obviously the question can be stated directly in $L^1(\mathbf{T})$ : is it possible to quantify the uniform integrability of a bounded sequence $(f_n)_n$ of integrable functions in term of Fourier coefficients ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, corrected, thanks !

Comment: What is uniform integrability and uniform integrability, it is a strange term.

Comment: @katago: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability

Comment: Also, by *compactness* you probably mean what I would call precompactness, namely, the compactness of the set $\overline{ \{ f_n \} }$ ?

Comment: Another remark is that if $f_n\to 0$ pointwise and $\{ f_n \}$ has compact closure, then $\|f_n\|\to 0$ (because norm limits also converge pointwise on a subsequence), and so the whole compactness business becomes spurious (it's just the condition that $f_n\to 0$ in norm). In terms of the Fourier coefficients, it's obviously equivalent to $\lim_n \sum_k |c_k(f_n)|^2 = 0$.

Comment: Christian Remling；thanks! I am checking this.

Comment: @ChristianRemling yes, this is a small (but frequent, at least in french) abuse of the wording " compactness ". I agree also with you that the whole question boils down to (strong) convergence to $0$. What bothers me with the condition you state is that it contains both uniform integrability and a.e. convergence. But say you have only uniform integrability for a bounded sequence of integrable functions : how do you see this on the coefficients ?

Comment: @AymanMoussa: The condition is simply $\lim \|f_n\|^2=0$, stated in terms of the Fourier coefficients. It doesn't imply that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise (only on a subsequence).

Comment: I know :) That's why I speak of (relative) compactness. Knowing that a sequence admits an a.e. converging subsequence forbids oscillations, like for instance $x\mapsto \cos(nx)$. My point is that the sequence $x\mapsto \sqrt{n}\mathbf{1}_{[-1/n,1/n]}$ also has a lack of (relative) compactness but for a totally different reason (concentration). The condition you specify solves the two issues together and my question is : is it possible to weaken it in order to focus on the concentration issue only ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer which I hope will clarify (in view of the above comments) my question.

A sufficient condition for $L^2$-uniform integrability is : for each $n\in\mathbf{N}$, $u_n:=(c_k(f_n))_{k\in \mathbf{Z}}$ belongs to some $\ell^p(\mathbf{Z})$ with $p\in[1,2)$ and $(u_n)_n$ is bounded in this space. Using
Riesz-Thorin theorem we get that $(f_n)_n$ belongs to some $L^q(\mathbf{T})$ space with $q>2$, with a uniform bound ; uniform integrability follows.

Note that this condition does not give any clue about a.e. convergence of a subsequence.

Of course it is far from necessary : $L^2$-uniform integrability is weaker than a bound in some $L^q(\mathbf{T})$ space with $q>2$. Even more : $(f_n)_n$ could be bounded in the later space without having its fourier coefficients bounded in some $\ell^p(\mathbf{Z})$ space with $p<2$ (because reverse Hausdorff-Young is false).